# Monotonically increasing polynomial intersection

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Say that I have two strictly monotonically increasing polynomials of the form
$f(x)=\sum^N_{i=0} a_ix^i, g(x)=\sum^N_{i=0} b_ix^i,$
with all coefficients $\geq 0$. Does it follow that they only intersect once in the interval $(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(x)=c_0+\cdots+c_Nx^n$ any polynomial with real coefficients. Then we can find for each $i$ positive numbers $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that $a_i-b_i=c_i$ (take $a_i$ and  $b_i$ large). Now if $f(x)=\sum a_i x^i$ and $g(x)= \sum b_i x^i$, we have $f-g=P$. If you take $P(x)=(x-1)\cdots (x-N)$, then $f$ and $g$ have the same value at $x=1,\cdots,N$.

Comment: This is the correct answer, though the question is trivial as stated.